# Python can't import blist classes

Tags: python

I'm trying to use the blist module on a remote machine which is too locked up to install aditional python modules. So, I'm compiling the modules and extending the sys.path to include the "manually compiled modules".However, I'm facing some issues with blist package.

I can import it fine however some of the classes don't work. For example:

sortedlist
sortedset
weaksortedlist
weaksorteset
sorteddict
btuple

They return:

```
  from blist import sortedlist
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  ImportError: cannot import name sortedlist
```

This functions are only available for python > 2.6 as they include Abstract Base Classes.

Is there anyway to check unsatisfied dependencies or any hint on how to make them work? I have no idea if this module is somekind of wrapper for other software (couldn't find any info in setup.py).

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

Apparently the problem is in the **init**.py (which I made empty to initialize the module). If I go inside the blist folder (there's a file _sortedlist.py there) and execute:

```
 from _sortedlist import sortedlist
```

the class is sucessfully imported. So, How can I initiate the module properly?

Comment: Try `import blist` and see if it imports.  If it does, fiddle around with that module to see what's in it.  Is it possible you have a different file named `blist.py` somewhere earlier on your path?

Comment: do you have pip or easy_install in the remote machine?

Comment: Can't use pip or easy_install. I have to do it this way.

Comment: import blist works but I think it ignores the failling classes :/ Source code of the sortedlist class doesn't give me any hint

Comment: Are you sure that `import blist` really imports what you want. As @BrenBarn said, this smells like a name clash.

Comment: Edited the question with some more info. Apparently the problem is in the module initialization

Comment: do `import blist` and then `dir(blist)` to see whats in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, managed to solve it.

In the **init**.py file I added the following lines:

```
from _sorteddict import sortedset as sortedset
from _sortedlist import sortedlist as sortedlist
```

now I can use (from outside of the blist module folder):

```
from blist import sortedsed,sortedlist
```

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

Consider also using the `SortedList` type from the [SortedContainers](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/) module. Some benefits: pure-Python, fast-as-C implementations, 100% unit test coverage, hours of stress testing. Because it's pure-Python, you can just pull the `sortedlist.py` file from the repository. Copy this file down:

```
https://github.com/grantjenks/sorted_containers/blob/master/sortedcontainers/sortedlist.py
```

and you're off to the races:

```
from sortedlist import SortedList
```

simple as that!